# ASP.NET MVC and WEB API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I already worked with ASP.NET MVC 4 in a project and Web Api with Web Forms in another project.

Is it possible to create a project with ASP.NET MVC as a frontend and Web Api as the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you simply want to utilize Web Api for data access instead of something like Entity Framework in an MVC project. You can easily do that. You just need to make HTTP requests with something like `HttpClient` that hit your Web Api, instead of using a `DbContext` instance from Entity Framework.

However, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you actually want to hit the Web Api from the frontend code, utilizing AJAX, then you're essentially talking about create a SPA (single page application). If all the interaction is happening purely client-side via JavaScript, then MVC becomes kind of moot. You can choose to use it or not, as a basic static HTML document would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no since both asp.net MVC and asp.net WebApi works on the backend.